# Realm executeTransactionAsync dont write data to DB

Tags: android, database, realm, kotlin

I use realm db in my project. I want to write some data from JSON in my assets folder to realm when app lauch first time. I use Kotlin. 
I init my realm:

```
  Realm.init(this)
    val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .rxFactory(RealmObservableFactory())
            .build()
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)
```

Than i want async-write `List<Data>` to my db:

```
val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
realm.executeTransactionAsync {
    realm.copyToRealm(skillsList)
}
realm.close()
```

But my realm db is empty. After `realm.copyToRealm(skillsList)` I have empty table. What is wrong? I check table with Stetho, its realy empty. How i can fix it?

Comment: Is this on a UI thread? Have you checked if closing the realm in onsuccess/onerror callback works?

Comment: Its onCreate of Application class. I put Log.d to CallBacks(onSuccess, onError). But Logcat is clear.

Comment: Are you sure you added the custom application class to the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score -1):

I had an error:

```
Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created
```

I fix it with:

```
   Thread({
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().use {
                val skillsList = ArrayList<Skill>()
                val inputSkills = assets.open("skills.json")
                val size = inputSkills.available()
                val buffer = ByteArray(size)
                inputSkills.read(buffer)
                inputSkills.close()
                val json: JSONObject = JSONObject(String(buffer))
                val skillsArray = json.getJSONArray("skills")
                (0..skillsArray.length() - 1)
                        .map { skillsArray.getJSONObject(it) }
                        .forEach { skillsList.add(Skill(skillsList.size.toLong(), it.getString("title"), it.getString("subtitle"), it.getInt("rating"))) }
                it.beginTransaction()
                it.copyToRealm(skillsList)
                it.commitTransaction()
            Log.d("REALM","LOOOOG")
        }
    }).start()
```